# How to Filter INNER JOIN SQL Command Results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, where-clause

I have a table which records form submissions.  For each submission of the form there are the following variables:

```
userid
record
accountName
accountNumber
```

When a user submits the form, the table is populated with a `record` value on each line item.  In other words, the values are all commonly linked by the `record` value.  I am trying to user `INNER JOIN` to filter the results onto a table that displays the `userid`, `accountName` and `accountNumber` as columns.  I am very close with this command:

```
SELECT t1.value AS number, t2.value AS name, t3.value AS userid
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t3
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.record = t2.record
WHERE t1.name = 'addAccountNumber'
AND t2.name = 'addAccountName'
AND t3.name = 'userid'
```

The only problem is that the results are not being limited to one per entry.  It appears that multiple instances are being shown on the table.

I believe there needs to be some editing around the `WHERE` portion of the statement.  It seems to me that the results are not picking up on the name values and filtering the results.  Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

---

UPDATED:

I should add that I do get the proper filtering results when I only include two rows in the call as seen here:

```
SELECT t1.value AS accountNumber, t2.value AS accountName
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2
ON t1.record=t2.record WHERE t1.name='addAccountNumber' AND t2.name='addAccountName'
```

Thought that may help show what I am coming from.  So, in general it is something to do with adding the `userid` variable that is giving me the trouble

Comment: Should there be an ON for the first JOIN?

Comment: that, or it needs to be in the from statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a difficult time understanding what you need, but maybe this is it.

```
SELECT t1.value AS number, t2.value AS name, t3.value AS userid

FROM mytable AS t1

INNER JOIN mytable AS t3 ON t1.record = t3.record

INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.record = t2.record

WHERE t1.name = 'addAccountNumber'

AND t2.name = 'addAccountName'

AND t3.name = 'userid'
```